# How Can I reduce one download time, when I have two webwork to download the same file?

Tags: web-worker, webassembly

In my web module, I have two webwork, one webwork to decode audio, another to encode audio.
In each webwork, I need to download a same wasm code(by now, I don't want to split the code). I want to know whether there is  a method that I can download once(like cache), and each webwork can use the code?

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add some example? I don't understand what are you asking, but I'll help if you explain the problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Cache via IndexedDB and check in your web worker if the webassembly module is cached.  See [this article on Caching compiled modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Caching_modules).